# How to return(skip the rest of) a function in swift if conditions are met

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield, segue, ibaction

I have a segue set up to perform when a button is pressed. I want to end the function and void the segue if the text field in the current view controller is nil. No luck so far. How would I go about doing this? Here is what I have:

```
@IBAction func myButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if textField.text == nil {

        return

    } else {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "theSegue", sender: sender)

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the documentation implies it (declared as optional), the `text` property is actually not `nil` (*This string is @"" by default*).

I recommend to check additionally for empty string.

```
@IBAction func myButton(_ sender: Any) {
   guard let text = textField.text, !text.isEmpty else { return }
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "theSegue", sender: sender)
}
```

Comment: You were faster answering question. Deleting my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. How would I do this if I have multiple conditions? ex: two Strings and I want to test both with .isEmpty

Comment: You can add multiple conditions comma separated: `guard condition1, condition2 else { ... `, `condition` represents `let ... .isEmpty` or something else which evaluates to Bool

Answer (score 2):

**Use `guard` or `if let` :**

```
guard let text = textField.text else {
            return
        }
```

Your code will like that:

```
@IBAction func myButton(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let text = textField.text else {
            return
        }    
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "theSegue", sender: sender)

}
```